# minSdkVersion on the Play Store not good

Tags: android, manifest

The problem I encounter is easy to describe . I'm developping an app for Android and this one is already present on the store for **beta** tests (only).

This is a part of the manifest.xml, with the well known lines:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Once I publish my app on the store, this file is read by the system and the field minSdkVersion should give information about the minimum required version  to install my app (if I have well understood). In my case, with the API 6 as the minimum SDK, it should appear on the Play Store, version 2.0 as the minimum version required. But it doesn't happen like that...

It shows that the required version is the 1.6 or newer...

Has I misunderstood anything?

Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: Cleaned everything and saved everything and Removed bin/ directory before compiling? Because minSdk 6 is really android 2.0.1. Maybe do a double-check and resubmit.

Comment: I have cleaned the project (clean up), I have removed bin before compiling et packaging my app and then reuploaded my apk, but there is always the same problem...

Comment: Problem resolved when publishing the apk in production...

Comment: Probably a bug in the play store then..

Comment: Do you have any more insight on this? I'm having a very similar issue right now where my minSdkVersion is "15", and the Play Store is allowing it on devices all the way down to version 7. This is in production.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776153/android-uses-sdk-minsdkversion-being-ignored-by-play-store

Comment: Looks like it's a bug http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67234/why-does-my-game-display-the-wrong-required-android-version-on-google-play